# strtok when process two strings at same time

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

New in C and pretty confused about how to deal with several strings at the same time using strtok, for a simply example, I want to use strtok to extract the number and compare then.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char s1[100]="11.54";
   char s2[100]="12.55";

   const char tok[2]=".";
   char* token1=strtok(s1,tok);
   char* token2=strtok(s2,tok);


while(token1 !=NULL && token2 !=NULL){
   int temp=strcmp(token1,token2);

   if(temp==0){
       token1=strtok(NULL,tok);
       token2=strtok(NULL,tok);

   }
   else if(temp<0){
     printf("%d\n",-1);
     return;
   } 
   else{
        printf("%d\n",1);
      return;
   }

}

if(token1 !=NULL){
  printf("%d\n",1);
  return; 
} 
if(token2 !=NULL){
   printf("%d\n",-1);
   return;
}

printf("%d\n",0);

return 0;
}
```

But when I use the strtok, the strtok(NULL,token)will point to the current string and will do like: 11->12>55->NULL and skip the 54

How could I deal with such situation? Thanks!!

Comment: `strsep` is also a good choice, if you have it.

Comment: As melpomene - `strtok()` can only handle one string at a time. Or, you could extract all the information you need from one string, then work on the other string.

Comment: As mentioned above strtok() can handle one string at a time. It tokenizes based on "." . So at first, your tokens are token1:11 , token2:12 which are unequal. It prints -1 and returns from while.

Answer (score 8):

Do not use `strtok()`. The documentation will tell you `strtok()` is not reentrant (i.e. should not be used across threads), but perhaps less obvious is the fact that the reason it is not reentrant is because it uses an internal `save` variable to remember where it's got to. That means you also can't use two instances at once. Instead use `strtok_r()` or failing that `strsep()` might work.

`strtok_r()` is just like `strtok`, save that you pass it a `char **` (i.e. a pointer to `char *`) where it can save where it's got to.

The [GNU libc manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) gives a good example of using a nested `strtok_r` which is what you are trying to do:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       char *str1, *str2, *token, *subtoken;
       char *saveptr1, *saveptr2;
       int j;

       if (argc != 4) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string delim subdelim\n",
                   argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       for (j = 1, str1 = argv[1]; ; j++, str1 = NULL) {
           token = strtok_r(str1, argv[2], &saveptr1);
           if (token == NULL)
               break;
           printf("%d: %s\n", j, token);

           for (str2 = token; ; str2 = NULL) {
               subtoken = strtok_r(str2, argv[3], &saveptr2);
               if (subtoken == NULL)
                   break;
               printf(" --> %s\n", subtoken);
           }
       }

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```