# Can I do a strtok of the token from another strtok?

Tags: c, strtok, httpserver

I have tokenized a buffer that I had, and at the point of the question, the token holds the following:

token = "Host: localhost:8080"

I'm trying to break apart each word so that I can check the HTTP request for "Content-Length: ", which will come up if I parse the next line. I am attempting to do this with another token, but every time I do the following, it overwrites the local token variable:

poken = strtok(token, " ");

[poken prior to the execution of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUxbu.png)

[spoken after it's execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYqOM.png)

Is there another way to isolate strings using spaces as a delimiter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [strtok when process two strings at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465800/strtok-when-process-two-strings-at-same-time)  - short answer No you can't do that.

Comment: `strtok` is not re-entrant or thread-safe. You must extract all the token pointers first, before processing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using **strchr** to locate delimiters, and **strstr** to locate words in your string.  **strtok** looks good but is generally not a good tool for parsing things.  When doing CSV files in particular  for "x,y,,z" one would expect to get 4 fields back.  You only get 3, as **strtok** will silently swallow the ",,".